# symfony2 model with custom primary key name (different than "id")

Tags: php, symfony, model, doctrine, primary-key

Can anybody paste an example definition of a `Symfony2`/`Doctrine` model which has a primary key that is different than *id* (the name, e.g. the primary key is *customer_id*)?

I've been searching the web for this and I've scanned entire cheatsheet (http://ormcheatsheet.com/) but couldn't find one.

For example, having following schema:

```
author:
  type: entity
  fields:
    id:
      id: true
      type: integer
      generator:
        strategy: AUTO
```

what should I change to replace *id* with *author_id* preserving it remains the primary key?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this?

```
author:
  type: entity
  id:
    author_id:
      type: integer
      generator:
        strategy: AUTO
  fields:
    name:
      type: string
      length: 50
```

[reference](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/yaml-mapping.html#example)